# Is the speed of sound the fastest rate that a chemical reaction can progress through a substance?

Tags: reactivity

I read that a martensitic transformation can travel at the speed of sound in that material. Is that confirmed as being the fastest speed of a chemical reaction (transformation)?

Comment: If the reaction front travels faster, you have an explosive.

Comment: @Karl Posted links in his comments here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/54282/79678 . Great link, by the way, and I will delete my other comment, since Karl has this!

Comment: @EdV On second thought, i think it is not *clearly impossible* that a solid solid transition spreads at a higher velocity. But of course ot cannot be much faster.

Comment: @Karl Based on wiki, stishovite is a polymorph of quartz that is produced in hypervelocity meteorite impacts. There is also a wiki article on “shocked quartz”. I have always assumed that melting was not involved, just shock.

Comment: Does a reaction or a phase transition A - - - > B need to propagate in general and in principle? Besides of seeds, this is obscure to me.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly, chemical reactions can propagate far faster than the speed of sound. If the reaction *emits* electromagnetic radiation, e.g. light, and is itself *initiated* by light, then the speed of propagation is the speed of light in that medium. See this article [from Sandia National Labs](https://fas.org/man/eprint/lhef.pdf), or from [the Royal Society](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1958.0127).

Comment: "If the reaction emits electromagnetic radiation, e.g. light, and is itself initiated by light, then the speed of propagation is the speed of light in that medium"  In such a case the propagation speed wouldn't be the speed of light, because you need to account for the time for the reaction itself. I.e., a particle emits a photon, it travels to another particle, a reaction (which takes times) takes place in which that particle emits a photon, that photon then travels to the next particle, and so on.

Comment: @theorist, no, that is only the case where the medium is so closely packed that light cannot propagate within it, and then the maximum speed would be far less. Consider a large lump of nitrogen triodide on one counter, and another a meter away. Theoretically (pardon the expression), light from one lump detonating should reach the other in 1/3*10^8 seconds. BTW, the Sandia lab is based on the idea that the detonation is propagated by light.

Comment: The propagation speed of a reaction is generally taken to mean the speed with which a reaction propagates *through the reacting medium*. That doesn't describe your system, in which you have two lumps of reactant separated by a meter in a darkened room and shine a light on the first lump, leading to the second lump reacting 1/3 *10^8 seconds later. That's simply a trivial consequence of any reaction that both produces, and is initated by, light. In addition, it makes the term "propagation speed" not chemically meaningful, since you now have a propagation speed that is independent...

Comment: .... of the specific physical chemistry of the reaction itself (except that that it produces, and is initiated by, light).  It is telling that the Sandia article you reference doesn't contain a single use of the terms "propagate" or "propagation"; it only uses "initiate" and "initiation".  The Royal Society article is in German, but the English abstract, again, only uses "initiation", not "propagation".  Perhaps a better phrasing to describe your set-up is that is allows separated reactants to *communicate* at the speed of light.

Comment: A better example is UV initiated epoxy resin curing. I just don't know if they are that transparent to UV.

Comment: @user2617804  I don't see how that would count as light-speed propagation.  With UV-initated curing, you're simply *initating* the reaction with something  that travels at c (photons).  Once the UV hits, and initates the reaction, that reaction doesn't then *propagate* the next reaction.  That requires another photon.  So the best way to describe this would be that the reaction *initiator* moves through the reacting medium at c.